# Microsoft Teams Export API Inquiry

Tags: api

Would it be possible to use this API to grab specific text out of Teams conversations when someone messages you, and to automatically send that to an Excel file?

More specifically, if someone sends a message with a certain keyword such as "JJJ" in the message, it will copy the entire message to an Excel file on a shared drive.

Would this API work in an Enterprise environment?

Oh and I'm somewhat new to Python so no offense taken if this is a stupid question :)

Comment: Have you checked the API docs?

Comment: Actually seeing in the documentation that the API is in 'preview' and only available to users who have a license for APIs. :(

Is the use of an API the only way?

Comment: It seems that the Graph API might work, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0.